# Lipschitz function $\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial U)$

Tags: real-analysis

The following function ($U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open set) $$\delta:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$ $$\delta(x) = \begin{cases}\!-\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial U)\!\!\!\!&,\;x\in {U}\\\! \;\;\,\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial U)  \!\!\!\!&,\;x\in \mathbb{R}^n-U\end{cases}$$ is Lipschitz-continuous?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both points in the interior or exterior, we follow this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/370238/119285, and see that, using the triangle inequality
$$d(x,\partial U)\leq |x-y|+d(y,\partial U),$$
so that if both points are in the interior this is equivalent to 
$$\delta(y)-\delta(x)\leq |x-y|$$
and if both points are in the exterior this is equivalent to 
$$\delta(x)-\delta(y)\leq |x-y|.$$
Switching the roles of $x,y$ gives the estimate for the absolute value, and thus the Lipschitz constant obtained is $1$.

When one point is in the interior and the other is in the exterior it is easier: as
$$|\delta(x)|\leq |x-y|$$ and simmetrically for $y$, the result follows from the triangle inequality
$$|\delta(x)-\delta(y)|\leq |\delta(x)|+|\delta(y)|\leq 2|x-y|,$$
so the Lipschitz constant is at most $2$.